# Using the Grails Stripe plugin

Tags: grails, stripe-payments, grails-plugin

I'm using [Stripe grails plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/stripe) in my application and I'm getting the below error:

```
Class:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyExceptionMessage:No such property: Stripe for class: com.myApp.app.SubscriptionRequestController
```

Here is my action:

```
def charge(String stripeToken, Double amount) {
    Stripe.apiKey = grailsApplication.config.grails.plugins.stripe.secretKey
    def amountInCents = (amount * 100) as Integer
    def chargeParams = [
        'amount': amountInCents,
        'currency': 'usd',
        'card': stripeToken,
        'description': 'customer@sample.org'
    ]

    def status
    try {
        Charge.create(chargeParams)
        status = 'Your purchase was successful.'
    } catch(CardException) {
        status = 'There was an error processing your credit card.'
    }

    redirect(action: "confirmation", params: [msg: status])
    return
}
```

i'm also getting the below error since i installed the plugin when i remove it i don't see it, it occurs while trying to access or refresh any view :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutResources tag. After rendering your page the following have not been rendered: [head]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

in your main layout file e.g.: main.gsp, have the two additional  both in body and head. Also, loads the stripe-v2 manually. No need to add it in web-app/js as the plugin itself already has it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <g:javascript src="stripe-v2.js" />
        <r:layoutResources/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:layoutBody/>
        <r:layoutResources/>
    </body>
</html>
```

in config.groovy add:

```
grails.resources.modules = {
    stripe {
        dependsOn 'jquery'
        resource url:'/js/stripe-v2.js', disposition: 'head', exclude:'minify'
    }
}
```

Sample gsp (taken from the docs) but i added payment-errors as the source use it:

```
<stripe:script formName="payment-form"/>
<g:form controller="checkout" action="charge" method="POST" name="payment-form">
    <div class="payment-errors"></div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Amount (USD)</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="amount" name="amount"/>
    </div>

    <stripe:creditCardInputs cssClass="form-row"/>

    <button type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
</g:form>
```

I think the plugin itself did not support the current implementation of Grails Asset Pipeline.I think it is not compatible for grails 2.4.3 and above.

Comment: now after making as the above i'm not getting this error anymore `java.lang.RuntimeException: It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutResources tag. After rendering your page the following have not been rendered: [head] ` but i still can't make a successful transaction also i notice that `Charge` action is not defined , see the screenshot http://postimg.org/image/k16zioat3/ , i tried to import `import com.stripe.Stripe` but i'm getting `unable to resolve class com.stripe.Stripe`

Comment: Sure, lets fix it by opening another question. Let me know once you have opened it and post your screenshot there. :)

Comment: If you accept this as an answer, can you accept this and close this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you probably aren't importing the `com.stripe.Stripe` class which is why you're getting that particular message.

You don't need to attempt to manually assign the secret key to the `Stripe` class. Just define `grails.plugins.stripe.secretKey` in your `Config.groovy` and the plugin will handle the rest, as you can [see in the plugin source](https://github.com/bobbywarner/grails-stripe/blob/6c86553d40d9f61d36b2107818e9e48bfa31249f/StripeGrailsPlugin.groovy#L33).

Comment: so what are the Stripe classes i need to import and in which package are they , i'm also always getting this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutResources tag. After rendering your page the following have not been rendered: [head]` since i installed the plugin !! when i remove it i don't see this error

Comment: That sounds like another question

Comment: i already edited the main post , but what are the packages that need to be imported?

Comment: i'm getting `Groovy:unable to resolve class com.stripe.Stripe`

Comment: What version of grails are you using? Currently the plugin have not been upgraded to grails 3.

Comment: @qusyairi Grails version is **2.5.1** , any ideas to make this work probably ?